Bipartite graph with degree conditions has matching of size at least $\frac{3n}{7}$
I am having trouble with the following:

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph on $n$ vertices. Let each vertex of $G$ have degree $3$ or $4$. Prove that $G$ has a matching of size at least $\frac{3n}{7}$.

I suppose I should use the following which I’ve seen and proved for bipartite graphs: for bipartite graph $G$ we have a matching $M$ such that:
\begin{equation}
|M| \geq \frac{E(G)}{\Delta(G)}. 
\end{equation}
Now we can consider a few cases, one of which is when $G$ is $3$-regular. Let $\Delta(G)$ denote the maximal degree in $G$. In this case $|E(G)| = \frac{3n}{2}$ and $\Delta(G) = 3$, hence $|M| \geq \frac{n}{2}$. The same holds if $G$ is $4$-regular.
Now $\frac{n}{2}$ is greater than $\frac{3n}{7}$ for all $n$. For example, let $n = 6$, then $\frac{6}{2} = 3 > \frac{18}{7} \approx 2.5714$. If $|M| \geq 2.5714$ then $|M| \geq 3$ and the result follows.
But this argument doesn’t always hold, such as when $n$ is a mil Maybe this isn’t right approach. Does anyone have a hint? Any help is appreciated.
I am also unsure about the case where there is a mix of vertices of degree $3$ and $4$, since the bound for $|M|$ is dependent on the number of vertices of degree $3$. I suspect that case could be done by induction.

@CalvinLin Yes thank you, I’ve edited the wording. For every bipartite graph there exists a matching $M$ with bounded size as stated. The inequality follows from $\Delta(G) \cdot \tau(G) \geq |E(G)|$ (where $\tau(G)$ is the size of a minimum vertex cover) and Kónig’s theorem.

@CalvinLin I don’t know about the result for the minimal degree. $\Delta(G)$ denotes the maximal degree in $G$. Also there are constraints on the degree, the maximal degree is either $3$ or $4$ since all vertices have degree $3$ or $4$, I’m not sure if the matching set is very large.

My apologies for the confusion.

Ah, my bad, $ \delta (G)$ is the minimal degree and $ \Delta (G)$ is the maximal degree. This should be good now.

Hint: Recall the proof of the quoted result $ |M | \geq \frac{ E(G) } { \max  \deg (v) } $.
It applies Konig's lemma to focus on the minimal vertex cover, and uses that each vertex can cover at most $\max \deg (c)$ edges. It implicitly assumes that we have that many vertices of max degree, which need not be true.
So in the event that we do not have enough vertices of the largest degree, we actually can produce a stronger result by accounting for the number of edges covered by a vertex of smaller degree. How can you express this mathematically?
One way to answer the hint:

 Suppose we have $ v_d$ vertices of degree $d$, so the number of edges is $E(G) = \sum v_d d  / 2$.
 The minimum vertex cover has a least $ \min( \sum m_d)$ vertices, subject to $ m_d \leq v_d $ and $\sum m_d d \geq E(G)$.

 To set the quoted result in this context, it occurs when we ignore the $m_d \leq v_d$ condition. Namely, for the largest degree $D$, let $m_D = E(G) / D$ (which could be $ > v_D$) and $m_d = 0 $ otherwise clearly satisfies $\sum m_d d \geq E(G)$, so $ \min(\sum m_d) = E(G) / D$ (with the ceiling function if you'd prefer).

Elaborating on the hint to this problem (with no further hints):
Suppose there are $a$ vertices with degree 3 and $b$ vertices with edge 4.
Then, there are $ \frac{ 3a  + 4b } { 2} = E(G) $ edges.
The minimum vertex cover in the above argument says we need at least $ \frac{E(G)} {4}$ vertices, but a necessary (though not sufficient) condition for equality is that  $b \geq \frac{ E(G)}{ 4} \Leftrightarrow b \geq \frac{3}{4} a$.
Case 1: $b \geq \frac{ 3}{4} a$, then there exists a matching of size $ \geq  \frac{ E(G) } { 4 } \geq \frac{ 3(a+b) } { 7 } $.
Case 2: $ b < \frac{3}{4} a $. How do we tighten up the bound? Can we still show that the number of vertices is at least $ \frac{ 3(a+b) } { 7 } $?
Applying the hint to answer Case 2:
We want to minimize $ c + d$ subject to $c \leq a$, $d \leq b$, $3c + 4d \geq \frac{3a+4b}{2}$, and $ b < \frac{3}{4} a$.

 $\min(c+d)$ clearly occurs when $d$ is maximized, so $ d = b$. This leaves us with $ 3c \geq \frac{3}{2} a - 2b$, or $  c \geq \frac{ 3a - 4b } { 6} $.
 Thus, the minimum vertex cover has at least $ \frac{ 3a-4b}{6} + b  = \frac{ 3a + 2b }{ 6} $ vertices.
 Finally, we verify that $ \frac{ 3a+2b}{6} > \frac{ 3a+3b}{7} \Leftrightarrow b < \frac{3}{4} a $, hence $G$ has a matching of size at least $ \frac{ 3a+2b}{6} > \frac{ 3a+3b}{7}$.

Corollary: Describe the equality case.
By chasing the details of the proof, the equality case requires

$4b = 3a$. So $ a = 4k, b = 3k$ for some $k$.

In particular, $ V(G) = a+b  = 7k$ is a multiple of 7.


The vertices of degree 4 form a vertex cover of the edges.

No vertex of degree 3 is used, so there is no edge between vertices of degree 3.
We have no spare capacity to allow for edges between vertices of degree 4.
Thus, all edges connect a vertex of degree 4 with a vertex of degree 3.


Conversely, given any bipartite graph where all edges connect a vertex of degree 4 with a vertex of degree 3.

By handshake lemma, $4b=3a$.
Pick all of the vertices of degree 4. Applying Halls Marriage Theorem to find the matching on the induced subgraph. This gives us a matching of size $ b =  \frac{ 3(a+b)}{7}$ vertices.


Thus, the equality case is when all edges connect a vertex of degree 4 with a vertex of degree 3.

Note: This graph need not just be the union of $ 3 \times 4 $ bipartite graphs.



Bonus: Generalize this argument to bipartite graphs where the vertices either have degree $p$ or $q$, and show that we have a matching of size at least $ \frac{ \min(p, q) |V(G) | } { p+q } $.

Thank you for your response, I'm still having trouble understanding the second case. I've tried rewriting the inequality or inferring something about $a$ or $b$ but to no avail. Also, in the 'one way to answer the hint' section, why is it that you can ignore the condition $m_{d} \leq v_{d}$ in my case?

1/ Note that it's just a hint (which was what you asked for), and not all of the details have been worked out. 2/ Not sure which is the "in my case" that you're referring to. If you're referring to the quoted result, then I'm just clarifying how the hint is a refinement.


Yes sorry, I have tried working out the details in the second case but I’m still stuck. 2. By ‘in my case’ I meant the graph $G$ where each vertex has degree $3$ or $4$. Why is it that we may ignore the condition $m_{d} \leq v_{d}$ at all? Couldn’t we end up adding more than the number of available vertices of a certain degree to the vertex cover.


@JLGL 1/  In future, if you're stuck, please lay out what you've tried. In this case, I've fleshed out the full details.  2/ For this problem, we may NOT ignore the condition $ m_d \leq v_d$. We didn't need to use it for Case 1, but we had to use it for Case 2 per the writeup.   $\quad$ To clarify, the quoted result of $ |M | \geq \frac{ E(G) } { \max  \deg (v) } $ does ignore the condition that $m_d \leq v_d$. We could "ignore" it for Case 1, but note that that case actually already satisfies $m_4 \leq v_4$, so actually it's more of "do not need to check it".

Thank you @CalvinLin this is very clear!
